# Background color (listview?)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In the image below is a gray area under my listview and above my button.  I want that area to have the same background color (black) as the list.

What seems odd to me is that in the emulator it's black, but on my phone, it's this gray.

[image]

I've tried setting the background color of the layout, the list, and the cachecolorhint... no matter what, it stays gray.

Current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#000000" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#00ccff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="#8b8b8b"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:textSize="12dp" >
    </Button>
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000" 
        android:layout_above="@id/AddButton"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

To be clear, I have no problem with the list when it fills the screen, it's when there's only a few items that don't fill the screen I get this gray background... I would much prefer it be the same black background as the list.

Comment: give android:cacheColorHint="#000000"  as #00000000. And what is the use of this TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like your phone is a Motorola running 2.3+ (Droid 3?).
I've seen the same "feature" on some Motorola phones.

Check [this post on Motorola Blog](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Blog/Why-Does-My-ListView-Look-Different/ba-p/17462) for a complete answer.
Basically, add on your `ListView` XML attributes `android:overScrollFooter="#000000"`.

It only works for 2.3+ devices, so you'd rather put it in a style in `res/values-v10/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector</item>
    <item name="android:overScrollFooter">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Then add this to your `theme.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>
```

Finally, apply your custom theme to your activity in your AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.listtest.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

I guess you can apply the style directly to the list, without passing by a theme, but this solution will work for all ListViews in your app as soon as you apply it to all your activities in the Manifest.

Comment: This looks promising, and it is exactly the issue I'm having.  I'll give the solutions a try when I get home and accept your answer if they work.  Thanks!

Comment: That was indeed the issue.  Much better looking lists now.

Comment: Oh dear god, wow, this worked after hours of thrashing. I did not have to add a theme, just specify the footer color. Many thanks and up-votes!

Answer (score 1):

// this looks fine for me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#000000" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#00ccff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="#8b8b8b"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="#000" 
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:textSize="12dp" >
    </Button>
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000" 
        android:layout_above="@id/AddButton"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don;t have a problem with the list (per se)... it's the area under it when it doesn't fill the entire screen.

Comment: my last try can you remove the id android:id="@android:id/empty".

Comment: Tried it, same result.  :(  I emptied the list, so the empty TextView came into play and the whole screen was black.  Add an item to the list and the gray screen under the list was back again.  It's got to be something to do with the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't *look* like the list is expanding the remaining space? Is that intended?

Also, to change the grey, wouldn't you need to set the background colour of the "empty" textview, since it appears to be spanning the entire height, I'm guess that's the textview that appears grey.

Comment: Nope.  Just tried to set the background of that textview to black, same gray underneath the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm not sure if this solves your problem...):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000" 
    android:layout_above="@id/AddButton"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

(The height of a listview should be always fill_parent)

Comment: Nope, still get the gray area under the listview when it doesn't fill the screen.